# Problem with using Uploadify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, uploadify

I have been trying to implement uploadify in my rails 3.1 app. And I followed the step mentioned [here](http://blog.bitcrowd.net/uploadify-paperclip-rails-3-and-sessions/). And here is my code:

```
{my form code here}
- arr = []
- request.env['HTTP_COOKIE'].each_char{|c| arr.push(c[0].to_s)}
- @session = arr.join("x")
= @sermon_path = sermons_path
:javascript
  $('#sermon_sermon').uploadify({
          uploader: '/uploadify.swf',
          script: '#{@sermon_path}',
          cancelImg: 'cancel.png',
          buttonText: 'Browse',
          auto: true,
          scriptData: { 'session_encoded': '#{@session}'}
  })
```

This did showed uploadify button to select file to upload, but when the file is selected nothing happens. It doesn't even shows the uploaded file and no response is sent back to server. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I newer use uploadify except in a php project but may be this other [tutorial](http://metautonomo.us/2010/07/09/uploadify-and-rails-3/) can help you. On github there is a working [example](https://github.com/rdetert/FormFly) and an [other](https://github.com/leeh/uploadify_paperclip_demo) but with rails 2.3.4 or you can simply try this [gem](https://github.com/mateomurphy/uploadify_rails3).